# My app crashes only when replacing a previous version

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I updated my game Upwords to use firebase for push notifications and also updated the build tools in the latest version.  Many (most?) of the users updating the game are finding it's crashing on launch. It seems the fix is to go into Settings->Apps->Upwords->Storage->Clear User Data.. then relaunch.  Anyone installing fresh is just fine.  I think I've reproduced the crash:

```
05-19 22:11:06.457 27138-27138/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords, PID: 27138
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords/com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:459)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:771)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity.setContentView(SlidingActivity.java:61)
    at com.lonelystarsoftware.upwords.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Seems like it's having problems with a TypedValue.. maybe one of my defined colors in my custom theme.  I've been reading that some have issues if they aren't using Appcompat so I've since added that but still seeing the same issue. I have a few color themes for my app (user selectable).. they are all based on this one:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I would love to put out another update to fix the crashing.. at the moment I'm just having to field a lot of support mails. Not ideal, but I suppose I could find a way to clear user data for this new version on launch and everyone would have to re-sign in, that might be a better solution then crashing on everyone.

Unfortunately my gameboard xml is too big to post here, it's a complex view, the main board game view. But I suspect it's having trouble with my colors.. most of the colors are defined like:

```
android:background="?boardColor"
```

If I remove those then it's crashing on another control which also has similar color definitions.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your xml

Comment: The error you're posting doesn't look like it's related to app data.

Comment: I agree, it's weird.  But I've absolutely confirmed that deleting app data related to the previous install allows the current version to launch.

Comment: Was going to post my gameboard.xml but it's too big, pushes the post past the 3000char limit.  But I've posted a relevant line that I think is the issue.  Something to do with updating the sdk build tools version made the user data incompatible it seems

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue.  In my pref file I store the color theme the user chose.  I looked at the pref file between my two version and though they are set to the same theme the values are diff.  One pref file has:<int name="theme" value="2131624186" /> the other has <int name="theme" value="2131624226" />.  When I set the value I do: setTheme(gameSettings.getInt("theme", R.style.Theme_MyApp_Default));   I suppose that int is not the same with each sdk version and I should store it a diff way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally tracked it down.  I have several themes that a user can select. I was storing the resource id of the selected theme in the user preferences so I can set it on subsequent launches. This mostly worked except when I updated the sdk build tools.. then those resource id's changed and I was setting the theme to resource id that either didn't exist or belonged to some other component.  I'm now just storing a simple enum int that maps to the different themes and the crashing is fixed.  I figured this out by using the Device File Explorer and diffing the shared pref file between the new and old versions of my app. Only one line was diff:

```
<int name="theme" value="2131624186" />
```

vs

```
<int name="theme" value="2131624226" />
```

Thanks for taking a look